# Some intersection of Schatten spaces gives a weak Schatten space?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, lp-spaces

Assume $1\leq p <\infty$. It is known that for all $q>p$
$$
S^{p}  
\subset S^{p,\infty}
\subset S^{q}.
$$
Out by curioisity, it is true that $\cap_{q>p} S^{q}=S^{p,\infty}$ ?

Recall that
$$
S^{p,\infty}
=\Big\{T \in S^\infty : s_n(T)=O_{n \to \infty}\Big(n^{-\frac{1}{p}}\Big) \Big\}.
$$

Comment: The intersection of $S^q$ for $q>p$ is a Fréchet space but $S^{p,\infty}$ is  a Banach space. Using the open mapping theorem, equality would most probably imply (or instance, if the intersection is dense in $S^p$) that $S^q=S^{p,\infty}$ for some $q$ which is not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The diagonal operator with $\ln(n)n^{-\frac{1}{p}}$ along the diagonal, for example, is in $S^q$ for all $q > p$ but not in $S^{p, \infty}$.